# Is WSE supported in .NET framework 4 / 4.5? Will it ever be?

Tags: .net, wse

We have to interface with some third party software which uses WSE. We really need them to upgrade to WCF but first I need to check if WSE will ever be supported in .NET4 / VS2012?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: WSE has been dead for a long long time; I remember reporting a fundamental critical bug *years* ago (it completely fails to handle MTOM correctly in some circumstances, I forget which - but very basic and very reproducible) - and the answer from connect was "will not fix". If core functionality was not getting bug-fixes, I don't expect any future. I can't even find the bug report on "connect" now, which seems damning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is no update for WSE to work with VS2008. Instead, VS 2008 relies on WCF for the same functionality.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Enhancements